# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host crash

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I am using VS2012. As you see in my question I am getting Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe stopped working when trying to open my website project. The weird thing is that even without building or compiling it, the error pops up. Sometimes I can get to host the website on IIS, but IIS crashes too, throwing the same exception.

Here are the details:

```
    Nombre del evento de problema:  CLR20r3
  Firma del problema 01:    microsoft.visualstudio.web.host
  Firma del problema 02:    11.0.50727.1
  Firma del problema 03:    5011ca46
  Firma del problema 04:    System.Runtime.Caching
  Firma del problema 05:    4.0.30319.17929
  Firma del problema 06:    4ffa5c57
  Firma del problema 07:    d8
  Firma del problema 08:    b
  Firma del problema 09:    System.StackOverflowException
```

Thanks in Advance

Note: I already tried repairing/reinstalling VS and didn't work.